# How to get ID3Tags information of a audio file in a specific URL?

Tags: java, id3-tag

I am trying to get a ID3Tag information from a audio file in a specific URL, after went throgh this topic i found a following code, it helps to retrive a ID3Tag information from a mp3 file. But my question is how i need to apply the below code that will return a ID3Tag information from a specific URL.

```
Mp3File mp3file = new Mp3File("SomeMp3File.mp3");
if (mp3file.hasId3v2Tag()) {
  ID3v2 id3v2Tag = mp3file.getId3v2Tag();
  System.out.println("Track: " + id3v2Tag.getTrack());
  System.out.println("Artist: " + id3v2Tag.getArtist());
  System.out.println("Title: " + id3v2Tag.getTitle());
  System.out.println("Album: " + id3v2Tag.getAlbum());
  System.out.println("Year: " + id3v2Tag.getYear());
  System.out.println("Genre: " + id3v2Tag.getGenre() + " (" + id3v2Tag.getGenreDescription() + ")");
  System.out.println("Comment: " + id3v2Tag.getComment());
  System.out.println("Composer: " + id3v2Tag.getComposer());
  System.out.println("Publisher: " + id3v2Tag.getPublisher());
  System.out.println("Original artist: " + id3v2Tag.getOriginalArtist());
  System.out.println("Album artist: " + id3v2Tag.getAlbumArtist());
  System.out.println("Copyright: " + id3v2Tag.getCopyright());
  System.out.println("URL: " + id3v2Tag.getUrl());
  System.out.println("Encoder: " + id3v2Tag.getEncoder());
  byte[] albumImageData = id3v2Tag.getAlbumImage();
  if (albumImageData != null) {
    System.out.println("Have album image data, length: " + albumImageData.length + " bytes");
    System.out.println("Album image mime type: " + id3v2Tag.getAlbumImageMimeType());
  }
}
```

But my question is how i need to apply the below code that will return a ID3Tag information from a specific URL:http://podcastdownload.npr.org/anon.npr-podcasts/podcast/510184/223365607/npr_223365607.mp3?_kip_ipx=1453569924-1421846382?

Answer (score 0):

You can write it to a mp3  file locally and then read it
I hope this code helps

```
    URLConnection conn = new URL("http://podcastdownload.npr.org/anon.npr-podcasts/podcast/510184/223365607/npr_223365607.mp3").openConnection();
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    OutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/tmp/SomeMp3File.mp3"));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int len;
    while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outstream.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    outstream.close();
    Mp3File mp3file = new Mp3File("SomeMp3File.mp3");
//and your reading code follows
```